# how to select an element from autoselect drop down in GoIbibo from city field using selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests

I was trying to automate flight booking in GoIbibo using selenium webdriver java. When we enter the value "from city", a list is displayed as autosuggestion.

But am not able to detect the elements in the autosuggestion using xpath. Also not able to find the exact xpath or id for the list displayed since am not able to inspect the list. I have used the below code to find the elements displayed but this is also not working.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("gosuggest_inputSrc")).sendKeys("Dublin (DUB)");
WebDriverWait nw = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
nw.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='gosuggest_inputSrc']//following-sibling::input")));
List<WebElement> orgins = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='gosuggest_inputSrc']//following-sibling::input"));
for (WebElement we : orgins){
    System.out.println(we.getText());
```

Please help in identifying the elements in autosuggestion list and selecting the needed element from the autosuggestion list. URL Used- https://www.goibibo.com/

Comment: Can you give me the url to try it out?

Comment: @Rajagopalan- URL- https://www.goibibo.com/

Comment: Now am able to identify the list but not able to select a value from the list. Please find below code 'WebDriverWait nw = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
  driver.switchTo().frame("notification-frame-22a3446b3");
  nw.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.fl_shAutosgBox:nth-child(1)")));
  List<WebElement> orgins = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.fl_shAutosgBox:nth-child(1)"));
  for (WebElement we : orgins){
   System.out.println(we.getText());
   if (we.getText().equals("Dublin (DUB)")){
    we.click();'

Comment: try the javascript executor to select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is the html of that list

```
<section class="\&quot;searchList" col-md-12="" col-sm-12="" col-xs-12="" autowrap="" pad0="" flt\"=""><div class="\&quot;searchListInnrWrap\&quot;"><div class="\&quot;width100" fl\"=""><ul id="\&quot;react-autosuggest-1\&quot;" class="\&quot;col-md-12" col-sm-12="" col-xs-12="" autowrap="" pad0="" autosuggestboxlist="" flt\"="" role="\&quot;listbox\&quot;"><li id="\&quot;react-autosuggest-1-suggestion--0\&quot;" class="\&quot;react-autosuggest__suggestion\&quot;" role="\&quot;option\&quot;"><div class="\&quot;\&quot;"><div class="\&quot;fl" padt5="" hidden-sm="" padr10="" hidden-xs\"=""><i class="\&quot;fl" icon-flights="" ico14\"=""></i></div><div class="\&quot;dib" col-md-11="" col-sm-12="" col-xs-12="" pad0="" textoverflow\"=""><div class="\&quot;mainTxt" clearfix\"=""><span>Dublin</span><!-- react-text: 466 --> <!-- /react-text --><span class="\&quot;txtTransUpper" ico14="" greylt\"="">(DUB)</span></div><div class="\&quot;fl" auto-ctryair-ellip="" mobellipsis="" padt2\"=""><span class="\&quot;clearfix\&quot;"><small class="\&quot;font12Lt\&quot;">Dublin Airport</small></span></div><span class="\&quot;fr\&quot;"><small class="\&quot;font12Lt" vmid="" padr5="" dib\"="">Ireland</small><span class="\&quot;flag-sprt" vmid="" dib="" ie\"=""></span></span><span class="\&quot;clearfix\&quot;">&nbsp;</span><!-- react-text: 475 --><!-- /react-text --></div></div></li><li id="\&quot;react-autosuggest-1-suggestion--1\&quot;" class="\&quot;react-autosuggest__suggestion\&quot;" role="\&quot;option\&quot;"><div class="\&quot;\&quot;"><div class="\&quot;fl" padt5="" hidden-sm="" padr10="" hidden-xs\"=""><i class="\&quot;fl" icon-flights="" ico14\"=""></i></div><div class="\&quot;dib" col-md-11="" col-sm-12="" col-xs-12="" pad0="" textoverflow\"=""><div class="\&quot;mainTxt" clearfix\"=""><span>Atlanta</span><!-- react-text: 483 --> <!-- /react-text --><span class="\&quot;txtTransUpper" ico14="" greylt\"="">(ATL)</span></div><div class="\&quot;fl" auto-ctryair-ellip="" mobellipsis="" padt2\"=""><span class="\&quot;clearfix\&quot;"><small class="\&quot;font12Lt\&quot;">Hartsfield Jackson Atlanta International Airport</small></span></div><span class="\&quot;fr\&quot;"><small class="\&quot;font12Lt" vmid="" padr5="" dib\"="">United States</small><span class="\&quot;flag-sprt" vmid="" dib="" us\"=""></span></span><span class="\&quot;clearfix\&quot;">&nbsp;</span><span class="\&quot;clearfix\&quot;"><small class="\&quot;font12Lt\&quot;"><!-- react-text: 494 --> <!-- /react-text --><span class="\&quot;fb\&quot;">(212</span><!-- react-text: 496 --> KMs from <!-- /react-text --><span class="\&quot;fb\&quot;">Dublin, United States)</span></small></span></div></div></li><li id="\&quot;react-autosuggest-1-suggestion--2\&quot;" class="\&quot;react-autosuggest__suggestion\&quot;" role="\&quot;option\&quot;"><div class="\&quot;\&quot;"><div class="\&quot;fl" padt5="" hidden-sm="" padr10="" hidden-xs\"=""><i class="\&quot;fl" icon-flights="" ico14\"=""></i></div><div class="\&quot;dib" col-md-11="" col-sm-12="" col-xs-12="" pad0="" textoverflow\"=""><div class="\&quot;mainTxt" clearfix\"=""><span>San Francisco</span><!-- react-text: 505 --> <!-- /react-text --><span class="\&quot;txtTransUpper" ico14="" greylt\"="">(SFO)</span></div><div class="\&quot;fl" auto-ctryair-ellip="" mobellipsis="" padt2\"=""><span class="\&quot;clearfix\&quot;"><small class="\&quot;font12Lt\&quot;">San Francisco International Airport</small></span></div><span class="\&quot;fr\&quot;"><small class="\&quot;font12Lt" vmid="" padr5="" dib\"="">United States</small><span class="\&quot;flag-sprt" vmid="" dib="" us\"=""></span></span><span class="\&quot;clearfix\&quot;">&nbsp;</span><span class="\&quot;clearfix\&quot;"><small class="\&quot;font12Lt\&quot;"><!-- react-text: 516 --> <!-- /react-text --><span class="\&quot;fb\&quot;">(60</span><!-- react-text: 518 --> KMs from <!-- /react-text --><span class="\&quot;fb\&quot;">Dublin, United States)</span></small></span></div></div></li><li id="\&quot;react-autosuggest-1-suggestion--3\&quot;" class="\&quot;react-autosuggest__suggestion\&quot;" role="\&quot;option\&quot;"><div class="\&quot;\&quot;"><div class="\&quot;fl" padt5="" hidden-sm="" padr10="" hidden-xs\"=""><i class="\&quot;fl" icon-flights="" ico14\"=""></i></div><div class="\&quot;dib" col-md-11="" col-sm-12="" col-xs-12="" pad0="" textoverflow\"=""><div class="\&quot;mainTxt" clearfix\"=""><span>Dallas</span><!-- react-text: 527 --> <!-- /react-text --><span class="\&quot;txtTransUpper" ico14="" greylt\"="">(DFW)</span></div><div class="\&quot;fl" auto-ctryair-ellip="" mobellipsis="" padt2\"=""><span class="\&quot;clearfix\&quot;"><small class="\&quot;font12Lt\&quot;">Dallas Fort Worth International Airport</small></span></div><span class="\&quot;fr\&quot;"><small class="\&quot;font12Lt" vmid="" padr5="" dib\"="">United States</small><span class="\&quot;flag-sprt" vmid="" dib="" us\"=""></span></span><span class="\&quot;clearfix\&quot;">&nbsp;</span><span class="\&quot;clearfix\&quot;"><small class="\&quot;font12Lt\&quot;"><!-- react-text: 538 --> <!-- /react-text --><span class="\&quot;fb\&quot;">(164</span><!-- react-text: 540 --> KMs from <!-- /react-text --><span class="\&quot;fb\&quot;">Dublin, United States)</span></small></span></div></div></li><li id="\&quot;react-autosuggest-1-suggestion--4\&quot;" class="\&quot;react-autosuggest__suggestion\&quot;" role="\&quot;option\&quot;"><div class="\&quot;\&quot;"><div class="\&quot;fl" padt5="" hidden-sm="" padr10="" hidden-xs\"=""><i class="\&quot;fl" icon-flights="" ico14\"=""></i></div><div class="\&quot;dib" col-md-11="" col-sm-12="" col-xs-12="" pad0="" textoverflow\"=""><div class="\&quot;mainTxt" clearfix\"=""><span>Cincinnati</span><!-- react-text: 549 --> <!-- /react-text --><span class="\&quot;txtTransUpper" ico14="" greylt\"="">(CVG)</span></div><div class="\&quot;fl" auto-ctryair-ellip="" mobellipsis="" padt2\"=""><span class="\&quot;clearfix\&quot;"><small class="\&quot;font12Lt\&quot;">Cincinnati Northern Kentucky International Airport</small></span></div><span class="\&quot;fr\&quot;"><small class="\&quot;font12Lt" vmid="" padr5="" dib\"="">United States</small><span class="\&quot;flag-sprt" vmid="" dib="" us\"=""></span></span><span class="\&quot;clearfix\&quot;">&nbsp;</span><span class="\&quot;clearfix\&quot;"><small class="\&quot;font12Lt\&quot;"><!-- react-text: 560 --> <!-- /react-text --><span class="\&quot;fb\&quot;">(163</span><!-- react-text: 562 --> KMs from <!-- /react-text --><span class="\&quot;fb\&quot;">Dublin, United States)</span></small></span></div></div></li><li id="\&quot;react-autosuggest-1-suggestion--5\&quot;" class="\&quot;react-autosuggest__suggestion\&quot;" role="\&quot;option\&quot;"><div class="\&quot;\&quot;"><div class="\&quot;fl" padt5="" hidden-sm="" padr10="" hidden-xs\"=""><i class="\&quot;fl" icon-flights="" ico14\"=""></i></div><div class="\&quot;dib" col-md-11="" col-sm-12="" col-xs-12="" pad0="" textoverflow\"=""><div class="\&quot;mainTxt" clearfix\"=""><span>Livermore</span><!-- react-text: 571 --> <!-- /react-text --><span class="\&quot;txtTransUpper" ico14="" greylt\"="">(LVK)</span></div><div class="\&quot;fl" auto-ctryair-ellip="" mobellipsis="" padt2\"=""><span class="\&quot;clearfix\&quot;"><small class="\&quot;font12Lt\&quot;">Livermore Airport</small></span></div><span class="\&quot;fr\&quot;"><small class="\&quot;font12Lt" vmid="" padr5="" dib\"="">United States</small><span class="\&quot;flag-sprt" vmid="" dib="" us\"=""></span></span><span class="\&quot;clearfix\&quot;">&nbsp;</span><span class="\&quot;clearfix\&quot;"><small class="\&quot;font12Lt\&quot;"><!-- react-text: 582 --> <!-- /react-text --><span class="\&quot;fb\&quot;">(14</span><!-- react-text: 584 --> KMs from <!-- /react-text --><span class="\&quot;fb\&quot;">Dublin, United States)</span></small></span></div></div></li><li id="\&quot;react-autosuggest-1-suggestion--6\&quot;" class="\&quot;react-autosuggest__suggestion\&quot;" role="\&quot;option\&quot;"><div class="\&quot;\&quot;"><div class="\&quot;fl" padt5="" hidden-sm="" padr10="" hidden-xs\"=""><i class="\&quot;fl" icon-flights="" ico14\"=""></i></div><div class="\&quot;dib" col-md-11="" col-sm-12="" col-xs-12="" pad0="" textoverflow\"=""><div class="\&quot;mainTxt" clearfix\"=""><span>Columbus</span><!-- react-text: 593 --> <!-- /react-text --><span class="\&quot;txtTransUpper" ico14="" greylt\"="">(CBM)</span></div><div class="\&quot;fl" auto-ctryair-ellip="" mobellipsis="" padt2\"=""><span class="\&quot;clearfix\&quot;"><small class="\&quot;font12Lt\&quot;">Colombus Airport</small></span></div><span class="\&quot;fr\&quot;"><small class="\&quot;font12Lt" vmid="" padr5="" dib\"="">United States</small><span class="\&quot;flag-sprt" vmid="" dib="" us\"=""></span></span><span class="\&quot;clearfix\&quot;">&nbsp;</span><span class="\&quot;clearfix\&quot;"><small class="\&quot;font12Lt\&quot;"><!-- react-text: 604 --> <!-- /react-text --><span class="\&quot;fb\&quot;">(18</span><!-- react-text: 606 --> KMs from <!-- /react-text --><span class="\&quot;fb\&quot;">Dublin, United States)</span></small></span></div></div></li><li id="\&quot;react-autosuggest-1-suggestion--7\&quot;" class="\&quot;react-autosuggest__suggestion\&quot;" role="\&quot;option\&quot;"><div class="\&quot;\&quot;"><div class="\&quot;fl" padt5="" hidden-sm="" padr10="" hidden-xs\"=""><i class="\&quot;fl" icon-flights="" ico14\"=""></i></div><div class="\&quot;dib" col-md-11="" col-sm-12="" col-xs-12="" pad0="" textoverflow\"=""><div class="\&quot;mainTxt" clearfix\"=""><span>Columbus</span><!-- react-text: 615 --> <!-- /react-text --><span class="\&quot;txtTransUpper" ico14="" greylt\"="">(LCK)</span></div><div class="\&quot;fl" auto-ctryair-ellip="" mobellipsis="" padt2\"=""><span class="\&quot;clearfix\&quot;"><small class="\&quot;font12Lt\&quot;">Columbus Airport</small></span></div><span class="\&quot;fr\&quot;"><small class="\&quot;font12Lt" vmid="" padr5="" dib\"="">United States</small><span class="\&quot;flag-sprt" vmid="" dib="" us\"=""></span></span><span class="\&quot;clearfix\&quot;">&nbsp;</span><span class="\&quot;clearfix\&quot;"><small class="\&quot;font12Lt\&quot;"><!-- react-text: 626 --> <!-- /react-text --><span class="\&quot;fb\&quot;">(18</span><!-- react-text: 628 --> KMs from <!-- /react-text --><span class="\&quot;fb\&quot;">Dublin, United States)</span></small></span></div></div></li><li id="\&quot;react-autosuggest-1-suggestion--8\&quot;" class="\&quot;react-autosuggest__suggestion\&quot;" role="\&quot;option\&quot;"><div class="\&quot;\&quot;"><div class="\&quot;fl" padt5="" hidden-sm="" padr10="" hidden-xs\"=""><i class="\&quot;fl" icon-flights="" ico14\"=""></i></div><div class="\&quot;dib" col-md-11="" col-sm-12="" col-xs-12="" pad0="" textoverflow\"=""><div class="\&quot;mainTxt" clearfix\"=""><span>Columbus</span><!-- react-text: 637 --> <!-- /react-text --><span class="\&quot;txtTransUpper" ico14="" greylt\"="">(OSU)</span></div><div class="\&quot;fl" auto-ctryair-ellip="" mobellipsis="" padt2\"=""><span class="\&quot;clearfix\&quot;"><small class="\&quot;font12Lt\&quot;">Columbus Airport</small></span></div><span class="\&quot;fr\&quot;"><small class="\&quot;font12Lt" vmid="" padr5="" dib\"="">United States</small><span class="\&quot;flag-sprt" vmid="" dib="" us\"=""></span></span><span class="\&quot;clearfix\&quot;">&nbsp;</span><span class="\&quot;clearfix\&quot;"><small class="\&quot;font12Lt\&quot;"><!-- react-text: 648 --> <!-- /react-text --><span class="\&quot;fb\&quot;">(18</span><!-- react-text: 650 --> KMs from <!-- /react-text --><span class="\&quot;fb\&quot;">Dublin, United States)</span></small></span></div></div></li></ul></div></div></section>
```

And your element is in span

```
<div class="\&quot;mainTxt" clearfix\"=""><span>Dublin</span><!-- react-text: 466 --> <!-- /react-text --><span class="\&quot;txtTransUpper" ico14="" greylt\"="">(DUB)</span></div>
```

use this line as soon as you declared your driver variable, so you don't have to use any Explicit wait.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

use this code to click it

```
driver.findElement(By.id("gosuggest_inputSrc")).sendKeys "Dublin (DUB)"
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[normalize-space()='Dublin']").click
```

Comment: Thanks @Rajagopalan. How did u get the HTML for the list.

Comment: @Dinu I am using WATIR which is a wrapper around Ruby Selenium Binding, I can get the particular block of Html using WATIR.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for selecting the city from the dropdown using keyboard keys for the goibibo round trip.

```
public class Goibibo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://www.goibibo.com/");
    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='roundTrip']")).click();
    WebElement text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='gosuggest_inputSrc']"));
    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    act.click(text).perform();
    act.sendKeys(text, "Bengaluru").perform();
    act.pause(2000).perform();
    act.sendKeys(text, Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform();
    act.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform();
    WebElement text1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='gosuggest_inputDest']"));
    act.click(text1).perform();
    act.sendKeys(text1, "Delhi").perform();
    act.pause(2000).perform();
    act.sendKeys(text, Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform();
    act.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform();
    
    driver.quit();

}
```

}